# moderncv banking style: add a extra line above the address information

Tags: titles, moderncv

I would like to add a extra information, but before the address information line, and after my name, of course.

How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome! Please add a Minimal Working example starting with `\documentclass ...` and ending with `\end{document}` so as people here can reproduce your situation and help you.

Comment: you have `\title{more informations}`

Answer (score 3):

The following minimal example patches `\maketitle` to insert a macro that contains "extra information" in the title for the [`moderncv`](http://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv) `banking` style. The command used to adjust this "extra information" is `\someextrainfo{<stuff>}`. You can also adjust the font, if needed, using `\someextrainfofont{<font>}`. Note that you may have to reset any such font changes using `\addressfont{<font>}`, as fonts are set using *switches*.

[image]

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\maketitle}% <cmd>
  {\addressfont\color{color2}}% <search>
  {\@someextrainfofont\color{color2}%
   \ifcsdef{@someextrainfo}{\@someextrainfo\\}{}%
   \addressfont}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\providecommand{\@someextrainfofont}{}
\newcommand{\someextrainfo}[1]{\gdef\@someextrainfo{#1}}
\newcommand{\someextrainfofont}[1]{\gdef\@someextrainfofont{#1}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\name{John}{Doe}
\someextrainfo{some extra information}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\quote{Some quote}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\section{A test section}
Some test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text

\end{document}
```

Comment: But, in this way the frase "some extra information" repeats twice, in the first line and in the end od the header.

Comment: @user81898: The macro `\extrainfo` already existed, sorry. I've updated that to use `\somextrainfo` (and `\somextrainfofont`).

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I edit Wener's code. Just to make a difference between the default extrainfo and this new extrainfo

```
The following minimal example patches `\maketitle` to insert a macro that contains "extra information" in the title for the [`moderncv`](http://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv) `banking` style. The command used to adjust this "extra information" is `\extrainfo{<stuff>}`. You can also adjust the font, if needed, using `\extrainfofont{<font>}`. Note that you may have to reset any such font changes using `\addressfont{<font>}`, as fonts are set using *switches*.


\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\maketitle}% <cmd>
  {\addressfont\color{color2}}% <search>
  {\@extrainfofont\color{color2}%
   \ifcsdef{@extrainf}{\@extrainf\\}{}%
   \addressfont}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\providecommand{\@extrainfofont}{}
\newcommand{\extrainf}[1]{\gdef\@extrainf{#1}}
\newcommand{\extrainfofont}[1]{\gdef\@extrainfofont{#1}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\name{John}{Doe}
\extrainf{some extra information}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\quote{Some quote}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\section{A test section}
Some test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text

\end{document}
```